# Connecting the Javascript CSS to the CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How would this code be made to work with CSS background images instead of html images.**

The thing is, this was made to work with html images, not, CSS background images.

Preloading with CSS and JavaScript

https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

**CSS:**

```
#preload-01 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-01.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
    #preload-02 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-02.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
    #preload-03 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-03.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```

**Javascript:**

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById("preload-01").style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image-01.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
        document.getElementById("preload-02").style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image-02.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
        document.getElementById("preload-03").style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image-03.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    const oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```

How would I be able to connect the above javascript code to CSS background images?

**My CSS Background Image Code:**

```
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/fOfpsiC.png) no-repeat 0 0, url(https://i.imgur.com/92kMrMf.jpg) no-repeat 0 0, url(https://i.imgur.com/WzHsnG7.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**This is how you would write them individually:**

```
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/fOfpsiC.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/92kMrMf.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/WzHsnG7.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**Also: All of this would need to be added**

```
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
```

**To this line:**

```
.style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image-01.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by connecting the javascript to the css background images. I guess you could use classes in your CSS and assign them to your elements through javascript?

Comment: How do you assign a class or id to body:after {  ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also: All of this would need to be added: body:after { content: ""; position: absolute; To this line: .style.background = "url() no-repeat -9999px -9999px";

Comment: I'm trying to get CSS background images to work with the javacript, instead of html images. The javascript code is set up to work with html images, not CSS background images. This is all new stuff added to the CSS: body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; That would need to be added to the javascript part.

Comment: Just manipulate with classes that assign some styles.

Comment: It'd probably be good if you could try and describe what effect you're looking to achieve; it's great to see the code examples, but, going by the code in the question, it's a little hard to know what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How would I add this : body:after { content: ""; position: absolute; To this line: .style.background = "url() no-repeat -9999px -9999px";

Comment: If that's what you want to do, have you tried `.style.content = ""` and `.style.position: "absolute"`?

Comment: This is how it would be written? .style.background = "url(image-01.png) .style.content = "".style.position: "absolute" no-repeat -9999px -9999px";

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('preload-01').classList.add('some-class');
        ...
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.some-class:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/fOfpsiC.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Is this what you mean?